# Prove $f$ attains every value in anopen interval

Tags: limits, continuity

How would you prove the following statement?

> Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Suppose that $f$ is not a constant function and $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = 0$. Then there exists an  $\epsilon$ > 0
>   such that $|f(x)|$ attains every value in the open interval $(0, \epsilon)$.

I started by using the definiton of limit to show that $|f(x)| \lt \epsilon$, and it seems like the IVT proof, but with an open interval.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty{+}}f(x) = 0$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty{-}}f(x) = 0$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I think OP means limits at $\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Comment: My bad, fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is non-constant there exist $a$ such that $|f(a)| >0$. If $0<r<|f(a)|$ then, by hypothesis there exist $b$ such that $|f(b)| <r$. Since $|f|$ is a continuous function IVP shows that $|f(y)|=r$ for some $y$ between $a$ and $b$. Hence the conclusion holds with $\epsilon =|f(a)|$.

Comment: Great answer, but how would you explain that there exists a $b$ such that $|f(b)| \lt r$?

Comment: It is given that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Hence there exists $M$ such that $|f(x)| <r$ whenever $x >M$. Just take any $b >M$. @AviAsks